# How to customize devise form css in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, sass

Command `rails generate devise:views` successfully created folders under `\app\views\users`

I am looking to customize the devise forms but not sure whether the css to be placed in `application.css` or i need to separately create `user.css.scss`. Googled a bit and check git doc for this but none is specifying for CSS handling in devise.

Let me know the correct way of handling it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Devise will use you default layout. So the CSS that you are using in your `views/layouts/application.html.erb` will be used in your generated devise views.

If you want devise specific layouts, you can create a `views/layouts/devise.html.erb` file where you can serve devise specific CSS. It will pick it up automatically because of Rails naming conventions.

The above will work for any controller, just add a file in layouts named after the controller eg. `views/layouts/reservations.html.erb` for `ReservationsController`

You can also add specific layouts for the `Devise::RegistrationsController` by making a directory `views/layouts/devise` and adding `views/layouts/devise/registrations.html.erb`

Answer (score 5):

If you are doing controller-specific stylesheets, that is, if you switched off automatic compilation of all of your stylesheets into `application.css`, you should name your stylesheet after a devise controller, e.g.:

```
registrations.css.scss
```

and add it to `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile` list in `assets.rb`.

The placement of the stylesheet is standard, `app/assets/stylesheets/` so watch for name collisions between devise's controllers and yours.

To pick up a controller-specific stylesheet in a layout you need something like this:

#### Rails up to 4.1

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag controller_name, media: 'all' if Rails.application.assets.find_asset("#{controller_name}.css") %>
```

#### Rails 4.2+

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag controller_name, media: 'all' if asset_present?("#{controller_name}.css") %>

# ...meanwhile, somewhere in the helpers...

def asset_present?(name)
  # Rails 4.1 had Rails.application.assets filled out in all environments.
  # Rails 4.2 has it filled only when config.assets.compile == true which is only
  # in development by default.
  if Rails.application.assets.present?
    Rails.application.assets.find_asset(name)
  else
    Rails.application.assets_manifest.files.values.map { |v| v['logical_path'] }.include?(name)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

To generate device view run this line

```
rails generate devise:views
```

and do what ever you want with page styling.

to read more Click [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)

Comment: I already mentioned it..the thing is ...I am looking for the right way to include css ..let me know your thoughts over it :)

Comment: You can write css in any .css file it will work on devise views and then you have include it in application.css file.